# Eclipse OpenMp c++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, openmp, eclipse-cdt

I have an Edge Detction project C++ using sobel algorithim that I should convert it to it's parallel equivelnt using OpenMp
I made the code on Eclipse and I've downloaded Eclipse for Parallel but it turned out that OpenMp works only on C project
is there any way to activate OpenMp on Eclipse C++ ,
I've tried adding -fopenmp but it didn't work

Comment: http://www.ipd.uni-karlsruhe.de/multicore/research/download/HowToGuide-OpenMP.pdf

Comment: it didn't work
I couldn't find POSIX thread library nor GCC 4.2

Comment: Did you install POSIX how it was suggested in the document?

Comment: Maybe try to get it work from the command line first. Then in eclipse

Comment: I couldn't find how to download it + the gcc 4.2 is no more available

Comment: What os and compiler do you use?

Comment: MinGw compiler for Eclipse

Comment: Ok but what os? Windows, Ubuntu, Mac OS? Because once i found out that a compiler flag on ubuntu has a different name on Windows

Comment: Try also this [tutorial on how setup Eclipse and OpenMP](http://www.ipd.uni-karlsruhe.de/multicore/research/download/HowToGuide-OpenMP.pdf)